# QQuickWidget grab image

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qquickwidget

I am saving an image of a `QQuickWidget` with several QML children but all I have is a blank image.

C++ side:

```
QQuickWidget* content..
content->setSource(QUrl("qml:/main.qml"));
QPixmap *pm = content->grab(QRect(QPoint(0,0),QSize(-1,-1));
pm->save("someFilename.png", 0, 100);
```

QML side:

```
Rectangle{  width: 5; height: 5; color: "yellow"; objectname: "rootobj"}
```

In the QML I wish to dynamically add children and be able to show them in the image. I have tried `QQuickWindow` `grabWindow` method with a connection to a slot and it works but it captures only the window visible area and I need to capture the whole QML.

I believe this is not rocket science just that I am not getting it somewhere. Thanks for your replies!

Addendum:

Ok, I do not think its the issue of before/after rendering since I can see all the qml children before I call the picture grabber. So sorry for not being precise.

c++ side:

```
QQuickWidget* content..
content->setSource(QUrl("qml:/main.qml"));
//do all my dynamic qml children adding
```

After I can visually see all my qml:

```
QPixmap *pm = content->grab(QRect(QPoint(0,0),QSize(-1,-1));
pm->save(....
```

Unless I am wrong, I dont think its rendering issue. Thank you!

Comment: Edited: See addendum in post.

Answer (score 3):

Issue is like Mido said. You can solve it like follows.

Create a class `Viewer`:

### viewer.h

```
class Viewer : public QQuickView{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Viewer(QWindow *parent = 0);
    Viewer(bool showBar);
    virtual ~Viewer();
    void setMainQmlFile(const QString file);
    void addImportPath(const QString path);

public slots:
    void beforeRendering();
    void afterRendering()
}
```

### Viewer.cpp

```
#include "viewer.h"

Viewer::Viewer(QWindow *parent)
    : QQuickView(parent)
{
    setWidth(800);
    setHeight(480);
    connect(this, SIGNAL(beforeRendering()), this, SLOT(beforeRendering()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(afterRendering()), this, SLOT(afterRendering()));
}

void Viewer::setMainQmlFile(const QString file)
{
    setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(file));
}

void Viewer::addImportPath(const QString path)
{
    engine()->addImportPath(path);
}
void Viewer::beforeRendering()
{
//
}

void Viewer::afterRendering()
{
//grab window
  QImage img = this->grabWindow();
    img.save(path);
//or your code
}
```

### main.cpp

```
Viewer *viewer = new Viewer;
//
///
//
viewer->setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/main.qml"));
viewer->show();
```

Comment: This method only works for showing things within the window area. If the QML object falls outside of it, the output image will not show it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that the capture screen is done *before* the rendering of the QML object.
In order to make it work you should connect the grab of the signal *after* rendering signal:

```
 connect(this, SIGNAL(beforeRendering()), this, SLOT(sltBeforeRendering()));
 connect(this, SIGNAL(afterRendering()), this, SLOT(sltAfterRendering()));
```

do the grab in `sltAfterRendering` slot.

To grab screen I use the `grabWindow()` function and I call it from QML.
It depends on the behaviour that you want from your software.

Try this:

### grabber.h

```
#ifndef GRABBER_H
#define GRABBER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QImage>
#include <QQuickView>

class Grabber : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
     explicit Grabber(QObject *parent = 0);
     Grabber(QQuickView *view);
     ~Grabber();
     Q_INVOKABLE void capture(QString const &path) const;
signals:

public slots:
private:
   QQuickView*  view_;

};

#endif // GRABBER_H
```

### grabber.cpp

```
#include "grabber.h"

Grabber::Grabber(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}
Grabber::Grabber(QQuickView* view) :
    view_(view)
{
}
Grabber::~Grabber()
{
    if(view_ != NULL)
    {
        delete view_;
        view_ = NULL;
    }
}
void Grabber::capture(QString const &path) const
{
    QImage img = view_->grabWindow();
    img.save(path);
}
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include "qtquick2applicationviewer.h"
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include "grabber.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QtQuick2ApplicationViewer *viewer = new QtQuick2ApplicationViewer;
    Grabber * grab = new Grabber(viewer);
    viewer->setHeight(480);
    viewer->setWidth(800);

    viewer->rootContext()->setContextProperty("grab", grab);
    viewer->setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/main.qml"));

    viewer->showExpanded();


    return app.exec();
}
```

Call it from QML with:

```
grab.capture(path + "imageName.png")
```

Comment: This method only works for showing things within the window area. If the QML object falls outside of it, the output image will not show it.