# Canvas image not grabbed in QQuickWindow

Tags: qt, canvas, qml, qtquick2

I need to capture an image from QML which has `Canvas` elements. Whereas `Canvas`es are displayed fine they are not correctly saved in the picture snapshots.

I have used `QQuickWindow grabWindow` method as described in the solutions of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31402752/qquickwidget-grab-image) link and the images are saved in the UI thread called by `afterRendering` signal (I have tried `frameSwapped` signal too). Result is that all QML objects are saved but not `Canvas` objects.

Both the `renderStrategy` and `renderTarget`of `Canvas`es are set to the default values. They are simple `Canvas`es as shown below:

```
Canvas {
    id:canvas

    onPaint:{
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(20, 0);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(-10, 90, 210, 90, 180, 0);
        ctx.stroke();
        //...
    }
}
```

I have noticed that the `afterRendering` signal is called multiple times.

Any suggestion is really appreciated! :)

Comment: Stab in the dark here... have you tried a different [renderStrategy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html#renderStrategy-prop) and/or [renderTarget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html#renderTarget-prop)?

Comment: I have tried Threaded for renderStrategy with no results but the doc says: "Canvas.Immediate - context will perform graphics commands immediately in the main UI thread." so I believe it should be immediate. I can try the other renderTarget.